# Splitting on multiple characters at once

Tags: c#, regex, string

I know it is possible to split a string on a character like:

> string[] s = someString.Split(',');

If I know the format of my strings are going to be comma delimited, or new line delimited, can I handle both of these are once? Can both be done at once?

I.e:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

or:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

or:

```
a, b, c, 
d, e 
f
```

How can I split on multiple characters at once?

Comment: You could use Regex.split with this expression `[^a-zA-Z]+`, add other characters you expect in your strings, e.g. _ or 0-9 if this is the case.

Comment: If you don't know what to expect, just that there is no comma, no newline, no space, then you can go straightforward with `[ ,\\n]+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)() method takes has an override that accepts an array of characters to split on.

```
string[] s = someString.Split(new [] { ',', '\n' });
```

Also, an optional parameter is the [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) value. Which allows you to specify if you'd like to remove blank/empty entries.

Comment: Can get very fancy with `string[] s = someString.Split(", \n".Split(' '));` :-)

Comment: Whoisj: Except you can't split on space. :-)

Comment: @MichaelG you most certainly can!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I meant, in the example whoisj posted, that the user could not pass a string as a split character, because his inner split would eat it.

Comment: @MichaelG Ahh, like that, yes you're absolutely right :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.Split(",\n\r".ToCharArray());
```

insert any char you want to the string.

Comment: It would create an empty string "between" `\n` and `\r`, if `\r\n` is used as a separator (e.g. typical `Environment.NewLine`). Consider `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.